# How to increase copy limit in tmux 3.1?

Tags: tmux

When I go into copy mode in tmux 3.1 with `CTRL-B [`, I am able to copy/paste only about 350 lines of text. I want to increase this limit. What do I need to add to my `.tmux.conf` file?

NOTES:

- yes, variants of this question have already been asked on SO and sister sites, but all of the answers I have come across are ancient and don't work; surely there's a simple way to increase this buffer in tmux 3.1+
- I'm using tmux 3.1c from homebrew on MacOS v11.2.2, iTerm2 v3.4.4. Oddly, this limit only seems to apply with iTerm2 locally on my Mac; when I ssh into a remote Ubuntu server (tmux 3.1b built from source), also on iTerm2, the limit seems to no longer apply. (And I use the exact same .tmux.conf file on both.)

Comment: please turn off built-in setting of system clipboard
`set-option -g set-clipboard off` and check again, don't forget to set a higher buffer size limit too after this changes

Comment: @Freeman I'm not following -- that option disables copying altogether.

Comment: I'm running into same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Archimondain It's been a while -- I don't think I did find a solution. If you do, pls share here

Answer (score 0):

check this out, you can put this line in your `.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-option -g history-limit 1000
```

be aware, if you set a very large default value, it can easily consume lots of `RAM` if you create many panes.

you can increase 1000 up to any number according to your `RAM`

don't do this because it allocates a lot of lines (and hence memory) to all windows, causing your device to cripple more history over time.

```
set -g history-limit 999999999
```

Comment: No -- this adjusts how far you can scroll back, but it does not alter the limit as to how many lines I can copy with tmux